# Abstract class or Protocol, what's the Cocoa recommended practice?

Tags: cocoa, protocols, abstract-class

I'm not sure if I should create an abstract class and a series of descendants that inherit this abstract class, or define a protocol. What's the best practice in Cocoa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends.

The abstract class + descendants pattern is known as a *class cluster* in Cocoa terminology. Well-known examples are `NSString` and `NSArray`. The main advantage of this approach is that you can implement methods on the base class that work in terms of a core set of methods and are inherited; for instance, a subclass of `NSString` only needs to implement `-length` and `-characterAtIndex:` for all public `NSString` instance methods to work (although it won’t be very efficient).

The downside of this pattern is that implementations *must* inherit from the base class, which can be a severe restriction in a single-inheritance language.

A protocol, on the other hand, can be adopted by any class, but can’t provide a base implementation. It’s a lot like a statically-checked version of duck typing; by adopting a protocol you claim you can quack, and by requiring a protocol you can restrict a parameter to quack-capable classes without requiring a specific base class.

If you’re planning to provide a standard set of implementations for your abstraction, you probably want a class cluster. If you want to communicate with an open set of objects implementing your abstraction, you probably want a protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to recommend a book called *Cocoa Design Patterns* it is a very nice book to look up how the Cocoa framework works and what paradigms are used.

[Cocoa Design Patterns on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321535022)

Comment: You are welcome. BTW I am not associated with the book in any way, I just think it is helpful.